# Find RowNumber in Linq-SQL Or Entity Framework

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

How can I write the below SQL query using Linq-SQL or Entity Framework?

```
WITH tmpTable AS
(
    SELECT p.Id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY p.CreatedDate DESC) AS 'RowNumber'
    FROM MyTable p
)
SELECT RowNumber FROM tmpTable WHERE Id=12345;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't rewrite that query using LINQ.  You can use SQL queries in EF, or you can write a LINQ that fetches all the Id's ordered by CreatedDate and count how many you skip over looking for that Id.